# Improper Integration $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\ln(x\pi^x)\,dx}{x}$ converges or not.

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I was trying to find whether the $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\ln(x\pi^x)\,dx}{x}$ converges or not. And after integrating I got

$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(x)+x\ln\pi)-\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(x)+x\ln\pi)$.  (Which I will define as A)

and I was lost there. Because I got $\infty$-$\infty$. Does that mean the integral diverges to something that is indeterminable.(not $\infty$ and -$\infty$)

Also I asked a question concerning the expression above here 
[L'hospital for inf-inf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910526/lhospital-for-inf-inf/2910529?noredirect=1#comment6012417_2910529)

And found that according to a fellow name gimusi, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[ \left(\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(x)+x\ln\pi\right) -  \left(\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(1/x)+(1/x)\ln\pi\right)\right]$$ (which I will define as B)

is, however calculable. And I calculated it to be approaching infinity. Does that mean the integral diverges (to infinity)? I am lost now.

Questions Summary:

1. Does A=B (doesn't seem so)
2. Does the integral converges or diverges? (And how to figure that out)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that

$$\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\ln(x\pi^x)}{x}dx
=\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\ln x +x\ln \pi }{x}dx
=\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x}dx+\int_{0}^\infty\ln \pi \,dx$$

and we can conclude here since both integrals diverge.

Note that for the limit we have

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(x)+x\ln\pi\right) -  \left(\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(1/x)+(1/x)\ln\pi\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(x)+x\ln\pi -  \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(1/x)-(1/x)\ln\pi$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(x)+x\ln\pi -  \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(x)-(1/x)\ln\pi$$

$$x\ln\pi -(1/x)\ln\pi \to \infty$$

but it can't be used to evaluate the integral indeed for the improper integral we need to consider for $a>0$ the two integrals

$$\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\ln(x\pi^x)}{x}dx=\int_{0}^a \frac{\ln(x\pi^x)}{x}dx+\int_{a}^\infty\frac{\ln(x\pi^x)}{x}dx$$

and the two limits at $0$ and $\infty$ for the two integrals are independent and must be evaluated separetely.

Comment: Big thanks to your effort for explaining. However, can you pls explain why integral of lnx/x from x =0 to x=inf diverges? I mean I can understand that from x=1 to inf, it diverges. But here there are both plus and minus infinity at . Visually, I plotted the graph of lnx/x on desmos and found that at 0<x<1 the area is approaching minus infinity whereas when x>1 the area is approaching infinity? I know that it's coming back to the same question of infinity minus infinity, but I still don't understand why. Also the transition from the expression in line 3 to line 4 seems incorrect to me.

Comment: It suffices note that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\log x}x$ diverges to conclude that the whole integral diverges. Thiems topic was discussed many times here on MSE, I try to find some link to those discussions.

Comment: For the second issue I’ve used that $$\log \frac1x=-\log x\implies \log^2 \frac1x=(-\log x)^2=\log^2 x$$